# Able to plot as lists, unable to plot as Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

The following data is able to be plot using `matplotlib` but not after converting into a Pandas Series. How can it be plotted using pandas?

**Without pandas**

```
scores = [Decimal('3.7989'),
 Decimal('4.7989'),
 Decimal('5.7989'),
 Decimal('6.7989'),
 Decimal('7.7989')]

 timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 21, 21, 52),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 21, 21, 8),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 21, 21, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 21, 20, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 21, 19, 33)]

 plt.plot(timestamps,score)
```

[image]

**Using pandas**

```
ts = pd.Series(scores, index=timestamps)
ts.plot()
```

We get the error: `TypeError: Series has object dtype and cannot be converted: no numeric data to plot`

Comment: Huh. Did you accept the answer without voting for it as useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking away the `Decimal` type:

```
ts = pd.Series([float(x) for x in scores], index=timestamps)
```

or

```
ts = pd.Series(scores, index=timestamps, dtype='float64')
```

Pandas only supports float and integer as numeric types, Use anything else, and it becomes an "object."